# Spock mock not triggered in the Spring Integration Test

Tags: spring, mocking, spock, testcontainers

I'm racking my brain over this scenario (below code is simple for the sake of short description, the problems lies with jpa repository and maybe some spring context?):

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SomeClass {

  private final SomeJpaRepository repository;
  private final SomeBean someBean;

  private void method() {
    final String context = repository.findByName(contexName);
    someBean.doSthFurther(context);
  }
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SomeBean {

  private void doSthFurther() {
    //do sth
  }
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SomeService {
  private SomeClass someClass;
  public void execute() {
    //do stuff
    someClass.method();
    //do other stuff
  }
}

@TestConfiguration
class IntegrationTestMockingConfig {
    private DetachedMockFactory factory = new DetachedMockFactory()

    @Bean
    SomeBean someBean() {
        factory.Mock(SomeBean)
    }
}

@Testcontainers
@ActiveProfiles("integration-testing")
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class PostgresEnvironment extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mvc;

    static PostgreSQLContainer sQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:latest")
            .withDatabaseName("foo")
            .withUsername("foo")
            .withPassword("secret")
            .withReuse(true)

    def setupSpec() {
        sQLContainer.start()
    }

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void overrideProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry){
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", sQLContainer::getJdbcUrl);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", sQLContainer::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", sQLContainer::getPassword);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.driver-class-name", sQLContainer::getDriverClassName);
    }
}
```

and finally my Specification scenario:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [IntegrationTestMockingConfig])
class ScenarioToBeVerified extends PostgresEnvironment {

    @Autowired SomeBean someBean;


    def "scenario to verify interactions"() throws Exception {

        given: ''

        def xyz = create()
        
        when:
        var response = someService.execute()

        then:
        1 * someBean.doSthFurther(_)
    }

}
```

This is a simple SpringBoot application. The problem is that 1 * someBean.doSthFurther() verification fails as 0 interactions.
The problem lies in the line:
**final String context = repository.findByName(contexName);**
SomeService calls SomeClass and it method method() which further inside calls jpa repository and my mocked class.

If I remove this line, the verification of interaction passes successfully. I have a green test. If I call repository interaction verification fails. Test is red.

What is happening with the line of calling jpa repository? I'm not mocking it, I'm simply mocking some other class but it seems that my SomeClass which has two dependencies:

1. jpa repository
2. some class which is mocked by Spock

fails (in the debug mode I can see that the someBean.doSthFurther(context); is being called. So why specification doesn't see it and validates successfully?
My Jpa reposiotry is simple:

```
@Repository
public interface SomeJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeEntity, UUID> {
  
}

@Entity
public class SomeEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  UUID id;
}
```

I'm utterlly lost :( :( I don't use @SpringBean as I share my mocks and stubs betweens other specifications.
Spock version - 2.4-M1, spring boot 2.7.3

I would appreciate some advice...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Help us help you by learning [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and providing a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code you shared is incomplete, e.g. `someService` is completely missing. Furthermore, please also share the versions of Spock and Spring (Boot) you are using. Any reason why you are not using `@SpringBean` for the mock?

Comment: What happens if you remove the verification `1 * someBean...` it could hide an exception thrown by the preceding call.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot, it was suffocating a deep spring context error. Saw that with debug level trace. Your hint helped a lot!

Comment: @Agata, if your problem is solved, please write your own, comprehensive answer. Later, you can even accept your own answer in order to mark the question as answered and help other community members. If part or the whole of your solution was following Leonard's advice, please mention that in your answer. Thank you.